# Is it possible to catch native Exception in Java when Android WebView crashes?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium

There is a WebView in my app. Sometimes the WebView crashes after loading url. The crash may occur when executing some js code, since the logcat shows my APP exits unexpectedly after onLoadFinish.

the cash log is:

```
    java.lang.Throwable: jni-crash
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'alps/full_rlk6580_we_c_m/rlk6580_we_c_m:7.1.1/NMF26F/3:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    Author: collect by 'libunwind'
    ABI: 'arm64-v8a'
    pid: 2690, tid: 2835, name: RenderThread  >>> my.package.name <<<
    signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0x67616d79

    backtrace:
        r0  c557d300  r1  67616d69  r2  00000000  r3  01010032
        r4  00000001  r5  00000000  r6  00000032  r7  00000001
        r8  00000001  r9  c54fd010  r10 00000001  r11 c54d1710
        ip  cad7f9c4  sp  cd46f000  lr  00000001  pc  deac6022

        #00 pc 007a6022  /system/app/webview/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
    --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

and the chromium version is `Android 7.1.1 /Chrome 62.0.3202.73`.

This crash does not occur every time when loading the same url. What should I do to prevent this happen and is it possible to catch the exception in Java Code?